Residuals changes with Predicted values range in LGBM regressor
I am doing a regression problem  where the target variable ranges between 0.01 to 0.15. The model gives the best value when the predicted value is around 0.1. Plotting the residuals seems to show heteroscedasticity. However I couldn't find a way to overcome this.
Any further steps to Analyze and debug this

[Edit2] Visualizing within range.

[Edit] Visualizing with less points


You are probably modeling a mean, not a variance.

Thanks for you comments . How to ensure that i model for variance instead of mean  .Sorry to ask ,  I am just a novice here .

A model for the variance is very uncommon. Maybe your plot is slightly misleading due to overplotting. The flat lines on the top left and bottom right are simply because your response is bounded.

I tried plotting with less data . It shows similar trend .

To me, the plot looks great. Heteroscedasticity is irrelevant when you want to model the mean.

@MichaelM , Thanks for your comments. In the plot above  the predicted values range from (0 to 0.12). The residuals are high when the predicted values are around 0.02 compared to around 0.1 . Isn't this heteroscedasticity . Probably ,Another dumb question.. why do you say i am modelling the mean ?

You are modelling the mean because you are (probably) using an objective like "squared error" or "log loss" or similar. As said: there is no assumption of homogeneity. Thus, the plot looks good.
